# How to save file into network share folder

Tags: php, windows

I am trying to save xml file into share folder.But I am getting below error.

```
Warning: fopen(\\XYZ-server\xml\10052.xml):  failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

PHP code

```
$myFile = "\\\\XYZ-server-server\\xml\\$caseref.xml";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

I check that folder's permission.Everyone can create/delete/update files.

is there a way you can specify the credentials to be used to access a network share?

Comment: `fopen` is used for open file from a particular location not for saving file.  Show your file move/copy code.

Comment: check your file exist or not.... by using php file_exists('filename')

Comment: or you can use __DIR__ for real directory.

Comment: How are opening the file? Pleas edit the complete `fopen()` line into your question.

Comment: __DIR__."XYZ-server-server\\xml\\$caseref.xml";  try this.

Comment: @kreya be sure to set proper share permissions otherwise the file won't be created.

Comment: @urfusion My bad. Sorry :-)

Comment: @devpro: I tried this but same error

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what username PHP is running under and that that user has the right permissions?  On our IIS server it runs as IUSR not as the user who is actually using the website.